# Conditional Defining a property in model object

Tags: swift

I have a model object and there are some properties in that object. Based on some conditions, I want a property to be defined there or not to be defined. For example, this property is my app version.

```
    class Person {

      var name: String
      var address: String
      var age: String

      // I want some condition here like if myAppVersion > 1.0 then add isChild 
      //  property to my model object other wise don't add that 

      var isChild: Bool

      // Normal property again
      var gender: String
    }
```

I want this behaviour because the properties are coming from the backend and all these properties are required, so if, for some reason, the BE doesn't send the a required property which the client is expecting, then I will crash. These properties have to be mandatory and not optional.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do this.**

Declare your parameter as an **optional** and set it to nil if you don't want it to have a value. You should create two separate classes if you want to have different implementations, but that would be pretty superfluous for just one little change.

If your application crashes just because a property has a nil value, you should *really* take a look at [optional handling in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/3151675) and [nullability in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25).

Comment: Agree with this. Your model property should still be optional even if it is required from a business-logic perspective. This will allow you to freely have different properties for different versions of the backend API.